# Battery is stuck on estimating

Tags: 16.04, gnome, battery

Even when my laptop is plugged in, it's stuck in an idle state(neither charging nor discharging) and the battery indicator is stuck on estimating and I am using Ubuntu GNOME

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

Comment: No suggestions or any advice from the community. Really looking forward for your advice

Comment: Having the same problem on a Thinkpad T530, tried 2 replacements and the battery is still stuck in estimating. Original OEM battery works just fine..

Comment: Having the same problem in an Acer Aspire S7.

Comment: Same problem on my Acer Aspire ES 17 running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I'm having the same problem using a lenovo g580

Comment: Just happened to my dell latitude 6410

Comment: Happens on Ubuntu 18.04, Dell Latitude 7480 as well.

Answer (score 3):

On some systems the embedded controller that performs the battery level handling can get stuck.  In these cases I've resolved the issue by removing all power from the laptop and removed the battery for a few minutes to ensure that the embedded controller has powered off.  Placing the battery back in the laptop has resolved the issue.

Comment: I have a Thinkpad with a built-in battery, i.e. no easy way to physically remove it. But there's a BIOS setting to temporarily disable the built-in battery on such Thinkpads. That worked for me.

Comment: That's useful to know, thanks for sharing that detail!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue. I took out my battery. Started my machine by directly connecting the power with out battery. After some time i switched off my machine reconnected the battery and started the machine. Now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

It happened to my laptop as well after an update. The battery was stuck at 84% for 3 days, while plugged in. It seemed as the laptop was not charging, and the LED indication showed that the battery was full.

I'm using a new HP laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

I checked the contents of the following files from directory "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0".

- energy_now
- energy_full
- status

Comparing energy_now to energy_full, the battery was indeed at 84% and status was *charging*; but energy_now did not increase.

Unplugging the laptop, letting it discharge for a few minutes and then plugging it in again, fixed it for me.

The value of status changed to *discharging*, and then *charging*; and after that energy_now started to increase.